# Machine vs Resource assignment with extra business logic

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm, genetic-algorithm

This problem is an Assignment problem, which I can solve with Hungarian Algo but the problem is the business logic with it. We have to assign resource to each machine considering the business logic of given below

**Machine vs Resource assignment**

the business logic given is :

**1. Each machine is related to some floor f1, f2, f3**

**2. Cost of each resource can be maximum to 2.5**

**3. The average cost for each floor must not greater than 2.5**

Lets take an example of 6 Machines and 6 resources we may have a solution as below
F1 - (M1-R1), (M2, R3), (M3, R2)
F2 - (M4-R4), (M5,R5)
F3 - ........(none)
suppose after getting the solution we found that the average cost for floor 1 is greater than 2.5 then this is not the solution we need to re calculate so how we can get the solution for such condition.

Comment: Please provide a more comprehensive description of the problem. What is to be assigned to what? As you mention the so-called hungarian algorithm, it must involve a bipartite graph. Which one?

Comment: Do you mean the [generalized assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem)?

Comment: Wow, I'm not an expert but if each resource can be assigned to each machine the problem is much more complex than the linear assignment problem. If you have a short set of values, you could try a backtracking approach. If not, try asking at http://math.stackexchange.com/ or another math specialized forum

Comment: @MarcoA.Hernandez Thanks  I know its complex, and the machine and resource would be 1000, and solution can have less number of assignment. Performance of the algorithm should be high but backtracking is taking so much time for 1000 records.